# Parsing - can't get data from PHP file

Tags: php, parsing

I'm trying to parse data from http://skytech.si/

I looked around a bit and I find out that the site uses http://skytech.si/skytechsys/data.php?c=tabela to show data. When I open this file in my browser I get nothing. Is the file protected and can run only from server side or something?

Is there any way to get data from it? If I cold get HTML data (perhaps in a table?) I would probably know how to parse it.

If not, would it be still possible to parse website and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the requests made;

```
http://skytech.si/skytechsys/?c=graf&l=bf0b3c12e9b2c2d65bd5ae8925886b57
http://skytech.si/skytechsys/?c=tabela

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /skytechsys/ on this server.
```

This website doesn't allow 'outside' GET requests. You could try parsing the data via file-put-contents but I don't think you will be able to get specific data tables (aside from those on that home) due to AJAX requests that need to be made. I believe the /data? is the controller to handle data which is not exposed via the API.

Answer (score 1):

When you open this URL in your browser you send GET request. Data returned under this address is accessible after sending POST request with params as follows *c:tabela*, *l:undefined*, *x:undefined*. Analyze headers next time and look on Network log if you are using Chrome/Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

If that website does not expose an API, it is not recommended to parse the data, as their HTML structure is prone to change.

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

And then you can interpret it with an HTML-parsing engine or with an regular expression (not recommended).